# htaccess rewriting double // after remving index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an url like this

```
https://example.com /index.php/Products/Description/nikon-d300/Id-9
```

and after removing index.php I have this

```
https://example.com //Products/Description/nikon-d300/Id-9
```

As you see I have `//`. How to remove one ?

thank you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/.*)?/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# Reroute to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cURL=/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to your `remove index.php` rule that is adding one extra `/` to make it `//`. Change that rule to:

```bash
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)?index\.php(?:/(.*))?/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

And make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.